# Generic print confirmation dialog

Tags: windows, printing

Is there a way to make Windows display a confirmation dialog when you print something, no matter what program you're printing from?

Something to the effect of: *"You're about to print 5 pages. Are you sure you want to send the job to the printer?"*

I explored my printer's settings in Control Panel, but didn't see anything.  Googling the issue brings up a number of commercial software products that will do this. However, I am looking for a solution that I don't have to pay for (and, preferably, does not involve installing new software).

Comment: Hack: Remove all paper from your printer, and every time you print it'll nag you to insert some.

Comment: @grawity Haha thanks, that's a good idea! That would work great for home use. However, I'm specifically looking for something that will work in a public access environment that experiences high amounts of printing.

Comment: Ah, I'm sure it'll experience high amounts of blindly clicking through the confirmation then. Maybe your printer driver has a "Print preview" option? That often opens a new window which you must go through.

Comment: Many enterprise printers offer a print-on-demand function that requires keying in a code or pressing a confirmation button to actually output the print job. It may also be possible to configure this on the computer in the print drivers. This requires the person printing to go to the printer and confirm they wish to print the jobs.

Comment: @music2myear Yes, I did see something like that in my printer's settings.  What I'm looking for specifically is a way of explicitly telling users how many pages they are about to print. Many of our users are not good with computers and they sometimes print more pages than they expected. Having a confirmation that displays the number of pages would hopefully help prevent this from happening.

Comment: @grawity A print preview option at the printer-driver level would actually be super awesome. I'd much prefer that over a simple dialog box. Haven't seen anything like that in my printer's settings.

Comment: Check out FinePrint (decently reliable not well supported) or iPrint (buggy when I used it, but more actively supported) or similar products. These install Print Queues that store your jobs and allow for automated reflowing and then bulk printing at a desired time. They may contain options or features to display the number of pages being printed. THOUGH, every print dialog I've seen, except for Internet Explorer's, shows the number of pages in the document.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks for the suggestions. The problem is that some users don't do print previews or just aren't knowledgeable enough to see the page count. My thought is that they're more likely to see the page count if it's in their face.

Comment: "You can lead a horse to water..." and all that. As an IT professional, its one of my ongoing frustrations how few people read the messages they are presented with. In my experience, you can put blinking lights and sirens and big buttons they have to press, and there will still be those who fail to "see" what they're being presented with. So, I educate and inform, and then I expect them to know what they are required to know, and if there are penalties for their failure to know, those are on them.

Comment: @music2myear I'm a dreamer, what can I say. ;) Thanks for the advice.